# Matter Modeling is Graduating!

Tags: discussion

I have some very exciting news to share: On December 16th, our site is officially moving out of Beta! This is a great sign that the SE network has faith in our site and thinks we are a valuable resource.

Now in the immediate aftermath, things probably won't look too different around here, but there are a few things to look forward to down the road.

1. **Election**- In Beta, technically all mods serve on a pro-tem basis, even if they are elected. With the site graduating, there will be an election sometime next year.
2. **Site features**- Not immediate, but we should start to get certain full site features, like being selectable as a migration site by other sites in the network and the ability to host community ads.
3. **Site customization**- this is probably a little down the road, but we are now on the path to getting some aesthetic upgrades. Probably nothing too fancy early on, but probably a custom color scheme, may be a logo.

With this, I wanted to take the time to thank everyone who has put their time into making this site a great resource for Matter Modelers and a great community to interact with. This wouldn't be happening without all your hard work over the last year and half.

Let's keep this momentum going into next year to keep the site growing and improving!